# Visual Studio Update Wizard MySql

Tags: mysql, entity-framework

I am running Visual Studio 2010, and attempting to update my Entity Framework project using the Update Wizard. When I attempt to add a single table from the MySql database, the add tab will show the table that I am attempting to add, however when I click finish, I get the following error message.

```
Unable to generate the model because of the following exception: 'An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.
    Fatal error encountered during command execution.
        Fatal error encountered attempting to read the resultset.
            Reading from the stream has failed.
                Attempted to read past the end of the stream.
```

I get the same error message if attempt to create the Entity Framework from scratch. In addition, Server Explorer shows that the connection is successful when I test it.

I have also contacted Host Gator who is hosting the database and they where not able to see any issues on their side.

Answer (score 0):

The problem ended up being that our shared server, was not able to handle the Update Request from the Entity Connector Framework and was timing out. Once we moved our database over to a different server we no longer had an issue.